# What's the word to describe this behaviour?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe one's behaviour that is *unnecessarily complicated*.

For instance, let's say John, he goes to use the public toilet. Unlike most ordinary people who just uses the toilet, flush, and then leave, he's behaviour is unnecessarily complicated. Every time he goes to the toilet, he would first, remove his outerwear, this includes his jacket, pants, and even his socks and shoes. He would then, wipe the seat with toilet paper and then layer the seat with the toilet paper, and puts all his attire back on afterwards.

What's the word to describe this kind of behaviour?

Comment: It's *obsessive/compulsive*.

Comment: It depends on its aetiology. It may be *obsessive-compulsive*, or it may be merely *eccentric* or *bizarre*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As patently opposed to *anal-retentive*.

Comment: OCD usually refers to cleanliness or going overboard because of germs... this guy is barefoot in a public restroom and his clothes are who knows where.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not so sure actually! Would this guy ever actually get around to taking a dump, what with all the preparations?

Comment: maybe the word is constipated

Comment: Toilets and toilet procedures, especially those in unfamiliar places, can have a huge impact on children. Many children become fearful of toilets. Often these anxieties can be retained into adulthood and be the cause of eccentric, and irrational behaviour, in an otherwise relatively well-adjusted person. In the same way some people are afraid of spiders, others can be afraid of toilets. The word being sought is probably no more than 'phobic'.

Comment: I'm not sure the bathroom elements of the example are relevant or a distraction from the intended meaning.

Comment: Why would you wish to live with this for long enough to need a short way of describing it?

Comment: I need more examples from this person in question.  And pictures of their bare feet under the stall.

Comment: *Scrupulously fastidious*?

Comment: overcomplicating ?

Comment: John is bonkers?

Comment: *Punctiliousness.*

Comment: @RyeBread After his attire removal, he then proceeded to climb up and squat on the seat. I wouldn't say he is overly obsessive about cleanliness though, but it's definitely not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Overwrought** means both “overly complicated” and “agitated or neurotic.” Either sense could apply here.

Answer (score 1):

**Pernicketty** could mean *unnecessarily complicated* of cetain behaviours:

```
placing too much emphasis on trivial or minor details; fussy.
"she's very pernickety about her food"
synonyms:   fussy, difficult to please, difficult, finicky, over-fastidious, fastidious, over-particular, particular, faddish, finical, dainty, punctilious, hair-splitting, exacting, demanding, critical, overcritical; More
informalnitpicking, choosy, picky;
informalfaddy;
informalpersnickety;
```

I think the example you give would more likely be labelled 'eccentric' as it doesn't conform to OCD behaviour. As @Ryebread points out, OCD is more likely to be associated with fear of germs in which case a sufferer would not remove his shoes in a public toilet - he'd be more likely to avoid public toilets altogether. OCD is however related to many other obsessive bahaviours and not all of them are related to hygiene/germ fears. So, depending on the behaviour and the sufferer, the *unnecessarily complicated behaviour* could be classed as OCD.

Comment: Interesting twist on finicky: (of a person) fussy about their needs or requirements (Google meaning)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the term *convoluted* here.